# How to VANILLA drag and drop on MOBILE

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I've got some code here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PrZqqR

What I wanna do is to achieve drag and drop behaviour on screens < 720 px

How do I need to specify my move function at the very end knowing that the box I wanna drag should be `position: relative` for this purposes. Only vanilla JS is welcome. Thanks!

```
else if (window.innerWidth <= 720) {
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        images[i].addEventListener('touchstart', touchstart);
        images[i].addEventListener('touchend', touchend);

    }
}

function touchstart() {
    window.startTime = new Date();
}

function touchend() {
    window.endTime = new Date();
    if (window.endTime - window.startTime < 1000) {
        // just show preview as time is < 1 sec
        // url for the img src
        let url = "url(" + this.childNodes[1].getAttribute("src") + ")";
        // hide preview text
        document.querySelector(".alert").style.display = "none";
        // set preview image
        target.style.backgroundImage = url;
        target.classList.add("back_set");

        // end of simple click event
    } else {
        // this section handels the dragging story
        // add shake and start dragging, time is > 1 sec
        console.log("more than 1 sec");
        // make draggable
        this.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
        this.style.position = "absolute";
        // make shake animation
        this.style.animation = "shake 1s infinite";
        var x = parseInt(this.style.left);
        var y = parseInt(this.style.top);
        this.addEventListener("touchmove", move);
    }
}

function move() {
    console.log("moving");
}
```

Comment: You are vanilla JS but you are using ES6 in the code you have.

Comment: I think ES6 counts as vanilla--I read it as "no libraries or frameworks" (jQuery, React, etc). Anyway, all I can see is one `let` here from ES6 at a glance..

Comment: @ggorlen exactly, that's the main point

Answer (score 1):

This way you can drag an element by touch and collect its id and final position.
It is actually working for me.

HTML:

```
<!-- Div element you want to drag with touch -->
<div class="draggable" id="_draggable">                    
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
let box = document.querySelector(".draggable");


box.addEventListener('touchmove', (e) => {
    //Gets movement in px of the touch movement
    let touchLocation = e.targetTouches[0];
    //Gets element data
    currentElement = e.target;
    //Gets element id
    currentElementId = currentElement.id;

    //Moves element
    box.style.left = touchLocation.pageX + 'px';
    box.style.top = touchLocation.pageY + 'px';
})



box.addEventListener('touchend', (e) => {
    //Picks up the id of the dragged element
    console.log(currentElementId)

    //Picks up the new element position
    let x = parseInt(box.style.left);
    let y = parseInt(box.style.top);

})
```

Remember the drag element must have `position: absolute;` or `position: relative;`

Please let me know if you need anything else.